# git status on same repo gives different results on 2 computers

Tags: git

This one's really messing with me. I've copied the repo two both machines and verified it is binary identical on both. One machine is running Windows 7 and one is running Windows 8.1. I ran `git status` on both machines through the Git bash terminal and see a huge difference in unstaged changes. Git gui programs like TortoiseGit show the same thing. Both machines are on Git 1.9.4, the latest for Windows. Both machines have the exact same Git settings - global and all. What could possibly be happening?

Comment: How did you copy the repo? Did you manually copy the .git folder, or did you clone the repository like you are supposed to do?

Comment: I manually copied it from one computer to the other. That shouldn't make a difference should it? Since the repos are binary identical? I thought clone was mostly to make getting remotes easier?

Comment: What are the changes?

Comment: A bunch of files that have already been committed show up as changed... 30 on one computer, 600 on the other. 100% for sure no changes have been made. I've run `git reset --hard` and no difference. Again - both entire directories including .git folder - are binary identical.

Comment: I don't know the internal structure of the .git folder. It's possible that some data in it depends on the environment in which it is located (folder, drive, OS, etc ...). I don't know if you can simply copy it.

Comment: Check your `core.autocrlf` settings for each repo on each machine.

Comment: Hmm. My understanding is that the distributed nature of Git means that a Git repo is valid and should behave in exactly the same way anywhere it is used regardless of any external factors. Anyone?

Comment: @Cupcake Like I said, all settings are identical, even global. autocrlf = false

Comment: "*My understanding is that the distributed nature of Git means that a Git repo is valid and should behave in exactly the same way anywhere it is used regardless of any external factors.*" This is not entirely true. Git repos don't share configurations with each other, except for whatever ends up in the `.gitattributes` file. Additionally, Git repos will respond to user and system config settings, which may vary between users and systems, of course.

Comment: Check what is changed in one of the "unmodified" files using `git diff file`. For example, changing the file mode bits (`rwx`) of a file will make the file "dirty".

Comment: I did check that... the diff shows all lines removed, and then identical lines added. I just don't get it.

Comment: @Cupcake the .gitattributes file has also been copied along with the repo, in the root of the repo.

Comment: And what is the behaviour if you `git clone` the repo on each machine? The cause of your problem may be the system permissions or some other obscure modifications that occur during the copy process...

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the encoding differences across machines. The same thing happened to me when I did a `git status` on the same repository on the same machine via different terminals (git bash and WSL in windows) where one terminal thought that the working tree was clean and the other thought that all the files were modified and needed staging. I did a `git diff` and saw that when viewed from WSL terminal, all the lines in all the files ended in `^M` and the other thought they did not.