# same git repo gives different results when copied - on same computer

Tags: git

I'm having an issue with Git. My repo is showing that some files are changed even though they haven't been. I run `git checkout -- .` to revert all of the changes but nothing happens. Then, I copy the whole repo folder to another folder (make an exact duplicate). Then I run the same command, it takes about 10 seconds longer, and it works! The status is now clean on the copied repo.

Does anyone have an idea of why it's doing different things on the same exact local repo when they are identical, only one was copied from the other?

Comment: Operating system and file system would probably be important here. I know, for example, the OS X file system is case preserving but not case sensitive, which can cause no end of grief with un-explained, non-existent, git "changes"

Comment: Again - this is on the same computer on the same hard drive, same OS, same everything.

Comment: It isn't about having the same OS, but rather about how the OS handled the copy of the folders, especially the .git/ If you were on a unix system, you could run a plain diff between the two folders.

Comment: Looks like you duplicated your question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173284/git-status-on-same-repo-gives-different-results-on-2-computers You should have edited your first one.

Comment: I did not duplicate this question. It is a totally different problem, but the fact that unchanged files are shown as changed is the same.

Comment: Given the lack of details, the only thing anyone can tell you is that git thinks there are differences. I would suggest using a tool other than git to compare the directories (Something like a diff of the output from 'find -s directory -type f -exec md5 {} \;' for unix and unix-like systems).

Comment: Lack of details? I thought I explained this very clearly. I have verified with a binary comparison tool that the repos are 100% identical to one another. When I say something such as identical or same - I mean it. ;-)